# Voice recognition using Google Glass

Tags: android, google-glass

Does someone know if the voice recognition of Google Glass is the same voice command as that on Android, or how to install the functionality on an android phone like the Galaxy S4. I think that is the same sdk but I don't know.

My question is because I want to do a program with voice recognition.

Answer (score 1):

Much of what you handle using an Android phone applies, but you should review the Google Glass provided information about voice recognition (https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/input/voice)